# Layout with list

Tags: android, layout, button, listactivity

I have a listactivity with the following layout-xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:myapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/se.javalia.myDrinks"
    >
    <Button android:id="@+id/saveButton" 
        android:text="test test" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <ListView  
        android:id="@+id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/android:empty"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/main_no_items" /> 
</LinearLayout>
```

Now, I'd like to add a button above the list that stays in place when the list is scrolled. 
Is it possible at all?

Thanks in advance
Roland

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's definitely possible, just add a Button before the ListView in your XML. If your View becomes more involved, I would change your LinearLayout to be a RelativeLayout, and then you can position the elements more easily.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, just add a button above the ListView.

Comment: It if only where that simple, it doesn't work. Now I only see the the button and no list.

Answer (score 1):

In your 1st LinearLayout you should add: android:orientation="vertical"

Comment: Bingo. This is your problem, Roland. For whatever reason, the default orientation is horizontal.